# To turn string into code

Tags: c++

My english is not very good, but, I hope, you will understand me.
I know that turning string into code is impossible in C++, but I just can't see another way of solving my trouble.

I have an array of structures. You can say that it's a database. The task is that user should make combined request. In console a user chooses two parameters of structure and makes a combined request.
Something like this

```
        cout<<"\nВыберите первый параметр для поиска:" // Choose first parameter
            <<"\n1. processor"
            <<"\n2. videocard"                    
            <<"\n3. display"
            <<"\n4. RAM"
            <<"\n5. size"<<endl;
        int first;
        cin>>first;
        cout<<"\nВыберите второй параметр для поиска:" // Choose second parameter
            <<"\n1. processor"
            <<"\n2. videocard"
            <<"\n3. display"
            <<"\n4. RAM"
            <<"\n5. size"<<endl;    
        int second;
        cin>>second;

        cout<<"enter searchkey for first value: "
        string search1;
        cin>>search1;
        cout<<"enter searchkey for second value: "
        string search2;
        cin>>search2;

        string parameters[ 5 ] = { "processor", "videocard", "display", "RAM", "size" };
        for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) // And that's where it all goes wrong.
        if ( arrayOfStructs.parameters[ first ] == search1 && arrayOfStructs.parameters[ second ] == search2 )
               cout<<"found a match"<<endl;
```

I know why code doesn't work. I'm really sure that exists a solution that looks similar to mine. My "solution" looks like enum, but enum in this case is not appropriate.
If you know the solution, please write it down below.

The full code of my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct computer
{
    string processor;
    string videocard;
    string display;
    string RAM;
    string size;

    string getFieldValue( int );
};

string computer::getFieldValue( int fieldNumber )
{
    stringstream str;

    switch (fieldNumber) 
    {
        case 1: str<<this->processor;
        case 2: str<<this->videocard;
        case 3: str<<this->display;
        case 4: str<<this->RAM;
        case 5: str<<this->size;
    }

    return str.str();
}

void coutAndWrite( computer aStruct, ofstream &aFile );

int main()
{
    setlocale( 0, "" );
    computer sklad[ 30 ];
    computer temp;
    int i = 0, j;

    ifstream fromFile("structury.txt");
    while ( !fromFile.eof() )
    {
        fromFile>>sklad[ i ].processor
                >>sklad[ i ].videocard
                >>sklad[ i ].display
                >>sklad[ i ].RAM
                >>sklad[ i ].size;
        i++;
    }
    fromFile.close();
    ofstream rezultaty("rezultaty.txt");

    for ( i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
            for ( j = 0; j < 29; j++ )
                if ( sklad[ j + 1 ].processor[ 0 ] < sklad[ j ].processor[ 0 ] )
                {
                    temp = sklad[ j + 1 ];
                    sklad[ j + 1 ] = sklad[ j ];
                    sklad[ j ] = temp;
                }

    while ( 1 )
    {
        cout<<"\nВыберите тип запроса:"
            <<"\n1. Простой"
            <<"\n2. Составной"
            <<"\n0. Выход из программы\n";
        int prostoiIliSostavnoi;
        cin>>prostoiIliSostavnoi;

        if ( prostoiIliSostavnoi == 0 )
            break;
        if ( prostoiIliSostavnoi == 1 )
        {
            cout<<"\nВыберите параметр для поиска:"
                <<"\n1. processor"
                <<"\n2. videocard"
                <<"\n3. display"
                <<"\n4. RAM"
                <<"\n5. size"<<endl;
            int parametr;
            cin>>parametr;

            cout<<"Введите ключ поиска: ";
            string poisk;
            cin>>poisk;
            cout<<"Результаты поиска: ";
            for ( i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
                if ( sklad[ i ].getFieldValue( parametr ) == poisk )
                    coutAndWrite( sklad[ i ], rezultaty );
        }

    }

    system("pause");
}

void coutAndWrite( computer aStruct, ofstream &aFile )
{
    cout<<"\nprocessor: "<<aStruct.processor
        <<"\nvideocard: "<<aStruct.videocard
        <<"\ndisplay: "<<aStruct.display
        <<"\nRAM: "<<aStruct.RAM
        <<"\nsize: "<<aStruct.size<<endl<<endl;

    aFile<<setw( 15 )<<aStruct.processor
         <<setw( 15 )<<aStruct.videocard
         <<setw( 20 )<<aStruct.display
         <<setw( 10 )<<aStruct.RAM
         <<setw( 10 )<<aStruct.size<<endl;
}
```

Comment: So, you list a number of items, and expect the user to type in one of them, and then you want to find the corresponding item in a `struct` - so that if the user says `processor`, you want `arrayOfStructs[i].processor`?

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do? What do you want the end result to be?

Comment: Mats Petersson. User should not say "processor" user enters the corresponding number of item.

Comment: I think you are trying to implement `... WHERE first=search1 AND second=search2`. @eoLithic can you show us a couple example elements in arrayOfStructs? and the type definition for arrayOfStructs?

Comment: Prashant. Sure, I'll update the main question. Wait a sec.

Comment: I don't understand the question... are you trying to destringify(to code) strings? That's impossible. However, you can write a hashtable that converts strings to enums or numbers or whatever..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break it into pieces. Let's ignore the loop and the double search, and focus on the core problem: getting a field's value when you have its field number (or name):

```
string Computer::getFieldValue(int fieldNumber)
{
    stringstream str;

    switch (fieldNumber) {
        case 1: str << this->processor; break;
        case 2: str << this->videocard; break;
        case 3: str << this->display;   break;
        case 4: str << this->RAM;       break;
        case 5: str << this->size;      break;
    }

    return str.str();
}
```

Given this helper function, it's now possible to write the checking code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (computers[i].getFieldValue(first)  == search1 &&
        computers[i].getFieldValue(second) == search2)
    {
        cout << "found a match" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "getting a field's value when you have its field number (or name)". Thanks, you explained my problem better than I did.

Comment: Code doesn't compile, but concept works - since there are multiple types in the fields, `int` and `string`. I suspect we could return a `string` from the `int` values with a little extra effort.

Comment: I've changed my code with given functions but my program is not working. It compiles, but doesn't work. I reupdated the full program in main message for you. It doesn't find any matches :(

Comment: UPDATE: no need to help, I understand why program didn't work. You have forgot to add 'break' after each case.